# Launch of terminal after system login takes around 60 sec, is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Here is my `.bash_profile`

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad

alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias cat='ccat'
alias chrome='open -a Google\ Chrome'
alias brave='open -a Brave\ Browser'
alias db='open -a DBBrowserforSQLite'
alias sublime='open -a Sublime\ Text'
```

`.bashrc` is empty

Successive terminal window launch or new tab openings are quite fast.

Comment: What happens if you move .bash_profile away and try again? What exactly do you mean with system login?

Comment: yes that was the problem, it loads instantaneously if I remove  '.bash_profile'

Answer (score 1):

Do you have several apps that launch during login? This could cause the delay you are experiencing. Go to system Preferences and click on Users and Groups. Once this opens click on the tab "Login Items" and you see a panel that looks like the following:

[image]

The app names that show up in the window are apps that are set o launch at login. The can prevent these from starting up by selecting one of the names and click the minus sign in the +- box indicated in the image. Removing many of these will speed up you login time.

If you do this be sure to unlock this panel by clicking on the "lock" icon so your changes will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delay calling `pyenv` as that can be slow to run?

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/132

If you

```
set -x
time pyenv init -
```

You can get a feeling for it. Or you could just comment out / delete that one line starting with

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Comment: Do you have many "start at login" items?  They will run after you login and depending on how many you have could create the problem you are having.

Comment: @jmh That was going to be my second recommendation. Might even be a great stand alone answer.

Comment: if you think it quailfiers as an possible anser i'll submit it.  thanks.